# Adding inline script to a jQuery html() return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a for loop & jQuery output to html(). to output a JSON response to a html div.

In the for loop, I am transforming each result as follows into the output variable:

```
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        var output = "";
        for (i in response.Products) {
            var productID = response.Products[i].ProductId;
            var OtherVariables = response.Products[i].OtherResponseFields;
            output += "<Some Other Code> <script type=\"application/javascript\"> ...some code unique to each productID... </script>";
        }
        $("#allResults").html(output);
    });
```

The output works fine when I do not have the following in the output variable:

```
<script type=\"application/javascript\"> ...some code unique to each productID... </script>
```

But it breaks when I do add it as per the top code sample.  I am looking at using the variable "clicks_productID" for the user to select a product quantity in a popup, before adding the product & qty to my database (not yet built).

Is there a better way of doing this (the results need to be different for each JSON return - which can be a variable response qty based on the submission)?

Comment: `"<div class='uk-width-medium-1-4'> <div class='md-card'> <div class='md-card-head uk-text-center uk-position-relative'>....` **is not** required for your question. Read [ask]. Pay close attention to MCVE. Correct your question.

Comment: @Amit It was relevant in so much as there might have been something else at play that I wasn't aware of, so I was giving as much info as I felt relevant.  I will remove it as I have now clarified the query as per HelloWorld comments, but at the time it could have been wholly relevant.

Comment: No. it was never relevant. Not because "in the end it turned out not to be", but because had you cared to "ask a good question" as explained in [ask], you'd take the effort to isolate your problem and remove boilerplate.

Comment: And you're edit, although welcome and improves your question is still quite far from minimal.

Comment: @Amit what else do you want to remove?

Comment: Let's see... now that you *know* the problem, can you think of an code fragment that would suffer from the same problem, but is shorter then yours? If you can (which I really hope is the case), then you should've arrived at that code **before asking the question to begin with**. Then, once you understand exactly what's not working, if you can't find an answer on the web (google...) or here on SO, ask a more specific question. You'd get tons of upvotes, a bunch of answers, and would've learned a great deal about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<script type=\"application/javascript\">var clicks_" + productID + " = 1;var minimum = 1;function updateClickCount_" + productID + "() {if (clicks >= minimum) {document.getElementById('clickCount_" + productID + "').innerHTML = clicks_" + productID + ";} else {clicks_" + productID + " = 1;document.getElementById('clickCount_" + productID + "').innerHTML = clicks_" + productID + ";}}</script>
```

to

```
<scr" + "ipt type=\"application/javascript\">var clicks_" + productID + " = 1;var minimum = 1;function updateClickCount_" + productID + "() {if (clicks >= minimum) {document.getElementById('clickCount_" + productID + "').innerHTML = clicks_" + productID + ";} else {clicks_" + productID + " = 1;document.getElementById('clickCount_" + productID + "').innerHTML = clicks_" + productID + ";}}</scr" + "ipt>
```

otherwise the interpreter will think the closing script tag in your string is the end of your script